# How to find records in first table that are not present in second table

Tags: t-sql, join

I have large table table_A that has all the records from a smaller table table_B. I want to join these tables to find only those records from table_A that do not match with table_B

Example:

Table_A has
1
2
3
4
5

Table_B has

2
3
4

I need the result to show:
result:

1
5

Comment: `SELECT COLUMN FROM Table_A LEFT JOIN Table_B ON(Table_A.column = Table_B.column) WHERE Table_B.column is null`

Comment: [`EXCEPT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @HABA - good answer...  I was just reading the page you referenced.  you should probably submit it as a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are different possibilities, but I would use the NOT EXISTS. For e.g.:

```
Select * 
FROM Table_A AS ta
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Table_B AS tb
  WHERE tb.Id = ta.Id
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wonder how the efficiency of this solution would compare to Christian's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ff. method in order to achieve this.

```
SELECT
    A.Value
FROM Table_A as A
LEFT JOIN Table_B as B
ON A.Value = B.Value
WHERE B.Value IS NULL
```